# How do I move a Google Sheets from one Google account to another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, migrate-data

I created a moderately complex Google Sheets in my personal account, which became popular amongst my colleagues and is now officially adopted by our team. Therefore, it would make sense to move it to a more "official" location, e.g. an account owned by our team or our employer.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only transfer ownership to someone that you have already shared the document with.

First click the share button, add the Google account email address, choose "Can edit" from the drop down menu and click "Save changes". Now click the drop down menu again, change it from "Can edit" to "Is owner" and click "Save changes". That should be all.

If this isn't working, then that is probably due to the limitations that are specified on Google's support pages: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en

Comment: I can't believe I didn't find this. Now I'm embarrassed. Unfortunately, I can't down vote my own question for lack of research effort.

Comment: "Sorry, cannot transfer ownership. Ownership can only be transferred to someone in the same organization as the current owner."